# Split array by percentage

Tags: powershell

I have some powershell code that returns a load of computers to an array from a SQL query.

The query return vary in the total number of members. I shuffle the array also.

I want to take that array and split it into four or five smaller arrays by percentage. I want to define the percentages beforehand. For example, I might want to see 25%, 25%, 25%, 25%. Another time I want to see 10%, 30%, 30%, 40% or another 5%, 35%, 30%, 30%.

```
$phasepercents = 0.1,0.2,0.2,0.25,0.25 #Percentage of machines in each 
group

# AD groups to be created, Group5 is not needed as all EUC machines will be 
# added in the final round
$Phase0group = @()
$Phase1group = @()
$Phase2group = @()
$Phase3group = @()
$Phase4group = @()
$computers = my sql query with returned computers

$totalmachines = $computers.count #Total No of machine in the collection

$Machinesineachgroup = @()
$phasestartnumbers  = @()

# work out the percentages
$counter = 0
foreach ($phasepercent in $phasepercents)
{
$value =  $phasepercent *= $totalmachines
$value =  [Math]::floor($value) 
$Machinesineachgroup += $value
#WriteToLog "[INFO]`t,Machines in Phase$counter is $value"
$counter +=1
}
WriteToLog "[INFO-S]`t Total Machines in each phases $Machinesineachgroup"
```

Comment: `$arr.Where({ $_.Percentage -gt 50 }, 'Split')` This will give you two arrays split on a certain number.  Your question is presently too broad to be answered concisely.  Please provide what you've attempted **_in your question_**.

Comment: Hi - first time posting, so apologies for not including what I've tried.

Comment: Hopefully the question is better now.. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will break your collection into batch sizes based on the % in the `$PercentageList` and then store those batches into an array of arrays. you could also modify it to store the arrays in properties of a custom object OR into a hashtable if desired. [*grin*]

```
$MasterList = 1..100
$PercentageList = 10, 30, 20, 40

$Index = 0
$BatchList = foreach ($PL_Item in $PercentageList)
    {
    $BatchSize = [math]::Round($MasterList.Count * $PL_Item / 100, 0)

    # the leading comma forces PoSh to NOT unroll the array
    #    instead, it is stored as whole
    ,$MasterList[$Index..($Index + $BatchSize - 1)]

    $Index = $Index + $BatchSize
    }

$BatchList[0] -join ', '
'=' * 30
$BatchList.ForEach({$_ -join ', '})
```

output ...

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
==============================
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
```

Comment: Thank you - this seems so much simpler! Hashtables are on my list to learn.

The final piece (I hope!) is how do I put each of those batches into their own arrays to be reused? I think the answer is obvious...  So, I would want to have batch 1 (10%) to be $batch1 and batch 2 (30%) to be $batch2 for example. I'm going to take each and pump them into an AD group later.

Comment: @NickCairncross - you are quite welcome! [*grin*]  ///// you can get each batch by addressing it in the containing array. the 1st is `$BatchList[0]`, the 3rd is `$BatchList[2]` ... the usual array addressing. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you , saved a lot of time.

Comment: @jaismeensandhu - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]